# PostgreSQL DateStyle "SQL, DMY" not working with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, date, jdbc

I have an application in Java 1.6 + PostgreSQL 8.2 and I am currently updating PostgreSQL to version 9.5.

The application is implemented using PostgreSQL's DateStyle "SQL, DMY" **(DD/MM/YYYY)**. However, when I upgrade the JDBC to the newer database version, the following exception is displayed:

> The server's DateStyle parameter was changed to SQL, DMY. The JDBC driver requires DateStyle to **begin with ISO** for correct operation."

Okay, I set the DateStyle to "ISO, DMY", but the DMY is not respected. The date format displayed by the database is YYYY-MM-DD.

```
SET DateStyle TO "ISO, DMY";
set


SHOW DateStyle; 
 DateStyle
-----------
 ISO, DMY
(1 record)


SELECT now()::Date;
 now
------------
 2016-11-08
(1 record)
```

How can I get **DD/MM/YYYY** date format respecting the JDBC requirement for DateStyle to start with ISO?

Tks!

Comment: Please post your Java code, since the problem is there.

Comment: Hi @AlexeySoshin. Tks for comment.
Which part specifically? The connection pool is a complex implementation.
If possible, to not impact my implementation, I would like to resolve this issue with changes to the PostgreSQL settings.

Comment: I don't think this relates to your connection pool or DB at all. Could you post full error stack trace?

Comment: With proper Java code you shouldn't depend on the date style at all. For retrieving the values you should be using `Statement.getDate()` and then do the formatting through `SimpleDateFormatter`. For _storing_ the values you should be using `PreparedStatement.setDate()`. Neither of those methods depends on the date style of the server or the client. You have to show us the code that retrieves or stores the data (whichever is giving you the problems)